# How can I run tests on Netbeans using phpunit installed on my Virtual Machine?

Tags: php, phpunit, virtual-machine

I am very new to Netbeans IDE and PhpUnit tests (Sebastian Bergmann). I am using VM for my regular development which has git and phpunit installed in it. I have also written few tests and able to run them successfully on my VM.

After installing Netbeans, I am having a hard time linking VM's phpunit to netbeans . Because of this, it is not able to find the path for phpunit.

I would appreciate if someone can guide me to config Netbeans to use VM's phpunit and run tests like the way I can run on my VM?

If that's the drawback of this IDE, then does any other PHP IDE support this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

This topic is covered on the [Netbeans Site](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html) provided that your NetBeans IDE install is in the VM machine as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reposne, but is there any other options w/o installing it in the VM??

Comment: You can run PHPUnit from the command line in the VM if it is installed there.  I normally run PHPUnit from the command line as part of a continuous build/deployment environment.  The PHPUnit manual (http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html) also shows how to configure for running from a command line.